# Is it safe if I forgot to put the handbrake on when I turn off the car?

Tags: automatic-transmission, car, handbrake

Earlier today, I forgot to put the handbrake on when I turn off our car. Is it totally safe or is it dangerous to our car? My car has an automatic transmission.

Comment: Manual or Automatic Transmission?

Comment: Automatic Transmission

Comment: I never use handbrake on automatic trans cars, Yes it is safe.

Comment: I don't in winter on a manual - just leave it in gear - freezing issues avoided.

Answer (score 4):

If the vehicle is an automatic and the transmission is left in park then yes it will be ok. However it is advised that the handbrake is used when the vehicle is parked.

If its a manual vehicle, then you should apply the handbrake even if the car is left in gear. Not just when you're around hilly areas either, as strong winds can cause a vehicle to start moving as can passing trucks etc. Also say the vehicle is hit by another vehicle whilst parked.. if there is no handbrake applied your vehicle would then be able to go rolling away causing perhaps another accident or injury to someone else.

Comment: Why is the handbrake required if the car is in gear?

Comment: Because say for example the car is shunted whilst parked etc it could still jump out of gear.. And if that occurred on an incline etc.. Well I guess you know the rest.